# What is the best bottom sheet library for flutter?

Tags: flutter

Maybe this is inappropriate for SO but I have looked on pub.dev and fluttergems first; it's hard to tell which are still maintained, and which have which key features etc.

https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet.

@jamesblasco is the allow to set initial size feature on the way? Is this library still maintained?

I am mainly considering the top 3 on flutter gems but possibly others.
We would like to
a) Have smooth animations
b) Have good internal navigation
c) nice syntax - so far prefer widget to showBottomSheet - maybe i could wrap
d) tap on point in backdrop and animate up if it's closed

Answer (score 0):

```
          showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return StatefulBuilder(builder:
                              (BuildContext context, StateSetter staTe) {
                            return Container(
                              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      bottom: 
                          MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                              
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                            });
                          });
```

You may use this BottomSheet On Gesture Detector :-)
and you also design it

[image]